# How to load Other Pages along with application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a a rails app.Some components like side menu and header are common for all pages,so I wrote those codes in application.html.erb. The Problem that I am facing is only the application.html.erb is loading while the application is running,other pages are not loading.What should I do to make other pages load along with the application.html.erb page?

Comment: provide some coding to understand what u wanna render n wer..

Comment: Got it,add '<% yield %>' in your application.html.erb file where we need to render other pages

Comment: Sounds like you also want to take a look at partials. There is a whole section on it in the Rails guide about Layouts and Rendering. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials